# Keep mongo schema in sync

Tags: mongodb

I work on a project that has a frontend in PHP and backend in JAVA. The application uses MongoDb. In both PHP and JAVA there is an ORM layer that maps the Mongo collection. The problem is sometimes it's hard to keep the mongo collection in sync.

A developer in PHP can add a new document property in it's implementation but there is nothing to warn the JAVA developer about this. Of course verbal and written communication can be a solution but in practice it's not bulletproof and hard to maintain.

One solution I could think of is to write an XML document and use that both for JAVA and PHP to generate the base ORM classes for it. The file will be up to date using a version system.

Do you know a good way to solve this problem ?
Are there any XML/JSON tools for Mongo mapping already implemented ?

Comment: How would you solve the same problem in MySQL, for example?

Comment: @sergio: The ORM generators will get the schema and generate classes for tables in MYSQL. Or you can just check the tables for column names but in Mongo there is not schema defined.

Comment: Why are new fields a problem? I can hardly imagine that. Suddenly removed fields are, of course, totally different story :)

Comment: Might be better in the long run to define access to mongodb through an api which only one side maintains.  That way the frontend can be simplified and the database layer can scale aside from the frontend service.

Comment: @ross - that would not be optimal from a performance point of view

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB does not (yet) enforce schemas, you need to put the schema somewhere else. Since you dealing with JSON data, maybe JSON schemas would be a good way to define the schema for the datastore.

You would then build both Java and PHP ORM layers so that they enforce the common schema (validate stuff against the schema before is stored to datastore).

http://json-schema.org/

Comment: Have you actually used any of the schema validators?  Curious if there is a recommended/consistent cross-platform implementation.  It looks like the [JSON Schema spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03) is still very much in draft mode.

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/akidee/schema.js with node.js to validate what gets stored to Mongo through my API. But I must admit that sometimes I wonder if I'm trying to re-invent the relational database..

Comment: Perhaps a bit too prescriptive, but there are occasions where some strictness is required for data quality :).  I've been playing with [JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV) which seems comprehensive.  Possibly useful for an approach where you want your data to be "schema flexible", not entirely "schema free".  Also having fun with the [mongodb-schema](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/) shell helper.